# Finding Best Matches in Two Lists

Tags: c#, string-matching

I have two lists of string, I need to locate one string from one of them and one string from the other list, which are best match each other among all matches between the two lists.

I would create a `List <tuple<string, string, int>>` which holds the strings of both lists and the distance, but that is costly in memory.

Comment: How do you define "best match"?

Comment: the two strings that have the lowest distance among all comparisons

Answer (score 0):

Would not if to be easier to do this more object-oriented?

```
public class Match
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; } 
    public string Value2 { get; set; } 
    public int Distance { get; set;} 
}
```

and then have

```
List<Match>
```